# Error in dynamically choosing a dataset in shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am a newbie to shiny dashboard. I want to dynamically select a dataset among different datasets uploaded and use it to display the dataset.

I have written the below code but i am getting an error,

Warning: Error in DT::datatable: 'data' must be 2-dimensional (e.g. data frame or matrix)

ui

```
ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "yellow",
                    dashboardHeader(title = "Analytics Workbench 2.0", titleWidth = 250,
                                    dropdownMenuOutput("msgs")),

                    dashboardSidebar(
                      sidebarMenu(
                        fileInput("Table1", "Train Data"),
                        fileInput("Table2", "Test Data"),
                        menuItem("Variable Analysis", icon = icon("edit"),
                                 menuSubItem("Uni-Variate Analysis"),
                                 menuSubItem("Multi-Variate Analysis"))
                      )
                    ),
                    dashboardBody(
                      fluidPage(
                        fluidRow(
                          column(12, box(title = "Train Data", width = 6, solidHeader = TRUE, status = "primary", 
                                       collapsible = TRUE, DT::DTOutput("dtable1")),
                               box(title = "Test Data", width = 6, solidHeader = TRUE, status = "primary", 
                                   collapsible = TRUE, DT::DTOutput("dtable2")))),

                        fluidRow(
                          column(12, box(title = "Structure", width = 6, solidHeader = TRUE, status = "primary", 
                                       collapsible = TRUE, verbatimTextOutput("str1")),
                               box(title = "Structure", width = 6, solidHeader = TRUE, status = "primary", 
                                   collapsible = TRUE, verbatimTextOutput("str2"))))


                    )
                    )
)
```

server

```
server <- function(input, output) { 

  Train <- reactive({

    if (is.null(input$Table1)) return(NULL)

    read.table(input$Table1$datapath, fill = TRUE, header=T, sep=",", na.strings = c(""," ",NA))

  })

  Test <- reactive({

    if (is.null(input$Table2)) return(NULL)

    read.table(input$Table2$datapath, fill = TRUE, header=T, sep=",", na.strings = c(""," ",NA))

  })

  dataset_1 <- reactive({
        switch(input$Datasets,
       "Train" = Train,
       "Test" = Test)
  }) 

  output$dtable2 <- DT::renderDT({
    DT::datatable(dataset_1(), options = list(scrollX = TRUE))
  }) }
```

Please help me solve this issue.

Thanks Balaji

Comment: Your `ui` and `server` components are not complete; for instance, where and how is `input$Table1` defined? Please revisit your code and make it self-sufficient and complete (even though I recognize it's hard to test since you are getting an error).

Comment: BTW, some thoughts: (1) instead of `if(is.null(input$Table2))`, use `req(input$Table2)`, it is a little more robust; (2) likewise, consider adding `req(input$Datasets)` to the beginning of your `dataset_1` reactive block, before `switch`, and same for within the `renderDT` block.

Comment: Hi r2evans, I have updated entire ui code.. please check now

Comment: Out of sync again ... `input$Datasets`? I think your bug might be that you should be doing `switch(..., "Train"=Train(), "Test"=Test())`, since both of those are supposed to be reactive calls.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now i fixed the error